# A Suitable Function for Terrain, Mountain Modeling

Tags: functions, contour-integration, 3d, surfaces

On Google Maps and various other mapping programs, one can see contour lines that correspond to elevation. Sometimes these contour lines are concentric corresponding to a mountain.

My question is what would be the most suitable function to represent such data? I thought the simplest choice would be multiple Gaussian "bumps" placed additively on a map; whose composition would define a certain map? Are there any other functional representation methods that could give this output?

My next goal would be fitting such function to a set of elevation data collected on a grid.

Comment: The answer probably depends on what you are going to use it for. My starting point would be 2-d interpolation of which there are many methods. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_interpolation

Comment: Thanks for the share. I will be going over the links referenced in the article. My goal: is finding a "flattest path" from source to a destination. That would probably trigger another question here! But if you've heard of any approaches, please do share. I worked with discretized PDEs, ODEs, and level sets before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a huge question...

It depends on the precision you'd like and on the kind of input data you have.

For discrete methods, you can use [Delaunay triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation). See for example [Delaunay Triangulation Algorithm and Application to Terrain Generation](http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/faniry/files/faniry_aims.pdf). You have commercial packages like https://www.geo-media.com/solutions/logiciel-covadis/modele-numerique-de-terrain.

[image]

You also have continuous methods that can be based on [spline surfaces](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4620/2013fa/lectures/17surfaces.pdf).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

RBF based interpolation worked great. I divide the world in degree blocks e.. 31-32 lat 40-41 lon would be one block, I sample about 40k elevation pts from each block and fit RBF Gaussian bumps, or multiquadric functions to smaller sections of a block. I save W matrix and lat, lons for the fit and I have my continuous function to recreate the terrain at any point.

https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00308008/document